# Qt-creator use dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll

How to access to functions in given DLL in Qt ?

Comment: Do you using QT creator or addin for visual studion? (or maybe something else)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the header file for the DLL in your source file, of course:

```
#include "MyDll.h"
```

Then, in the `.PRO` file, just add:

```
LIBS += MyDll.dll
```

Comment: Using g++ under MinGW, you don't need MyDll.lib. Using Visual Studio, I don't know.

Comment: i know that you need it if you use the MSVC.

Comment: You should just use `LIBS += -lMyDll` wich links to `MyDll.lib` for MSVC automatically or `libMyDll.a` for GCC.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Qt class "QLibrary". You can find a detailed description and examples at http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qlibrary.html

The main idea is, that you define a function pointer, assign it with QLibrary::resolve to the function in the dll, and you can then call it normally as any function.