# Is it possible to run a windows dll in Qt

Tags: c#, c++, .net, qt, dll

Can Qt link to a Microsoft dot net dll?

I'm having some legacy software rebuilt using Qt - Cross platform application framework. The legacy system included a drawing viewer which was basically a picture box that handled a dot net dll. All of the methods and commands needed to display the drawing and extract data are contained in the dll.

The way the DLL works is to ask the main application for the location of the drawing and a place to draw the graphics.  The problem is in the second of these two requests. This has to be a container which will support DOT NET graphics.

Can this be done with Qt?

Comment: Qt not QT then sorry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt-creator use dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834557/qt-creator-use-dll)

Comment: No problem to load and use any DLL with executable created with Qt except using .Net DLL sounds too tricky. That is not really about Qt then but using .Net code from native executable.

Comment: IMHO, it is simpler in the opposite direction: I remember that our team once provided a OpenGL view widget written in Qt which we provided as unmanaged code in a C# wrapper. This was embedded (by another company) in a C#/.net/anything application. I didn't myself the C# wrapping stuff and hence cannot provide details but at least I know it worked quite well finally.